# Can I implement typescript conditional types by javascript object values

Tags: typescript-generics, react-typescript

I am writing a React editor component, it could be used to write new posts or update an existing post.If used as an update editor, the props MUST receive title and content; if used as new post editor, title and content will not exist.

But I don't know how to let typescript access the "flag" props so that it could decide which interface it could use.

I want to use the component as follows:

```
    <PostEditor flag="newPost"/>

    <PostEditor 
        flag="updatePost" 
        title="a good story" 
        content="once upone a time"
    />
```

I write the interface as follows:

```
interface NewPostProps{
    flag:"newPost",
}

interface UpdatePostProps{
    flag:"updatePost",
    title:string,
    content:string,
}

type IPostEditorProps<T>= T extends "newPost"?NewPostProps:UpdatePostProps
```

I write the react component as this. It does not work. I want the flag props to be the generic type but I don't know how to write that.

```
export const PostEditor=({flag,title}:IPostEditorProps<T>)=>{
// component contents
    return (<></>)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Working example code:

```tsx
interface CommonProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  // ...other props that always exist
}

interface NewPostProps {
  content: never;
  flag: "newPost";
  title: never;
}

interface UpdatePostProps {
  content: string;
  flag: "updatePost";
  title: string;
}

type ConditionalProps = NewPostProps | UpdatePostProps;

type Props = CommonProps & ConditionalProps;

export const PostEditor = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { children, content, flag, title } = props;

  if (flag === "newPost") return <>{/* implement newpost */}</>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{content}</p>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Useful link: [conditional react props with typescript](https://dev.to/maissenayed/conditional-react-props-with-typescript-43lg)

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!